# How do I forcefully duplicate a nether portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen nether portals being duplicated due to linking problems before, but I can't seem to replicate that on purpose. I'm trying to create a sort of manual obsidian farm that doesn't involve withers and doesn't use the End. Alternate methods of obsidian farms are welcome, as long as they don't require me running 128 blocks in the overworld.

Here's what I've tried: A portal in the overworld, and a lever that is connected to a dispenser on a delay filled with lava(which breaks the portal). I thought that if I timed it right and flicked the lever right before entering the nether, it would break the portal and duplicate it upon reentering the corresponding portal in the nether. However, when I came back to the overworld, the lava placed at that exact moment and broke the portal THEN. Is this because the chunks were unloaded when I entered the nether? This setup wasn't built in the spawn chunks, and I can't move it to the spawn chunks since this is a server I doubt people would want their main portal to be replaced by a nether portal duplicator.

Comment: nether portals are checked (and, if no suitable pair can be found, generated) whenever any entity enters them. So what you can do is find a place somewhere far away from other nether portals in the overworld, build one manually, put a dispenser on a clock to dispense items through the portal, then stand on the other side and mine the freshly spawning portals. Plenty of yt tutorials on doing that, also using minecarts or similar.

Comment: You should put that as the answer.

Comment: I would've, but I didn't feel like this is enough detail to warrant a proper answer as I didn't include any explanation on how to set up the redstone etc. And I don't have the time to do that, so I figured a comment would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know a great way of duplicating portals (no multiplayer needed), although you will need at least 20 obsidian to make 2 portals.

Follow these steps:

1. Make a portal in the Overworld, then go through it.
2. Once you are in the Nether, go as far as you need to make your second portal.
3. Make a second one with the obsidian you have. Light it up.
4. Go through it.
5. Once you are back in the Overworld, break the portal you just got out of (the one that was generated in the Overworld) using your diamond pickaxe to mine it.
6. After that, go through the first portal you made earlier. After you are back in the Nether, you should still see the second portal you made in the **Nether** earlier.
7. Go through the second one again, and it should generate a new portal in the Overworld.

Repeat steps 5-7 as much as you need.

If this seems confusing, what I thought was that you needed extra portals, so maybe you can not only get infinite obsidian for extra portals, you can also use it for future builds.

If you are confused about anything, please let me know!